# How to create model in Django REST with userID from authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make a model with user ID as one of fields, but I want it to be created without needing to fill in userID field in POST request. Instead, I want the userID to be auto-filled from token authentication. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the [rest framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/). You can pass the `user_id` or `user` instance to the save method of your serializer. This can be done in the `perform_create` method of your `ViewSet`

```
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```